# How to create concentric triangles with Cairo?

Tags: c, geometry, cairo

I have three points that form a triangle (obviously). But I don't want to draw this triangle but a smaller one inside.

[image: Triangle]

How do I do that with Cairo in C?

Comment: Nicely illustrated question. More graphic questions should have illustrations. +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to calculate the vertices of new triangle whose sides are equidistant from the sides of the old triangle.

Find unit vectors for adjacent triangle sides **BD = BA / |BA|, BE = BC / |BC|**    ... (|BA| is length of vector BA)

Find unit bisector **BF = (BD + BE) / |BD + BE|**

Find final position of F point (bisector of needed length) **BF** = **BF** * NeededDistance / (**BF** x **BE**) ...(denominator is cross product, it is equal to Sin(ABC/2)

Do the same for G and H vertices.

[image]

Delphi code and result:

```
var
  P, V: array[0..2] of TPoint;
  i, inext, iprev: Integer;
  nx, ny, px, py, mx, my, coeff: Double;
  distance: Integer;

  procedure NormalizeVector(var dx, dy: Double);
  var
    revlen: Double;
  begin
    revlen := 1.0 / Hypot(dx, dy);
    dx := dx * revlen;
    dy := dy * revlen;
  end;

begin
  Canvas.Brush.Color := Color;
  Canvas.FillRect(ClientRect);  //clean the blackboard
  Randomize;

  //big triangle vertices
  for i := 0 to 2 do
    P[i] := Point(Random(500), Random(500));

  //draw big triangle
  Canvas.Brush.Style := bsClear;
  Canvas.Polygon(P);

  for i := 0 to 2 do begin
    inext := (i + 1) mod 3;  // next vertice index
    iprev := (i - 1 + 3) mod 3;  // previous vertice index
    nx := P[inext].X - P[i].X;   //vector to the next vertice
    ny := P[inext].Y - P[i].Y;
    px := P[iprev].X - P[i].X;   //vector to the previous vertice
    py := P[iprev].Y - P[i].Y;

    NormalizeVector(nx, ny);  //make unit vectors
    NormalizeVector(px, py);

    mx := nx + px;
    my := ny + py;
    NormalizeVector(mx, my); //unit bisector

    distance := 20;
    coeff := distance / (mx * py - my * px);
    mx := mx * coeff;
    my := my * coeff;

    //inner triangle vertice
    V[i] := Point(P[i].X + Round(mx), P[i].Y + Round(my));
  end;

  //draw inner triangle
  Canvas.Polygon(V);
```

[image]

Comment: That was fast and really helpful! Thank you!

Comment: Nicely illustrated answer. More graphic questions should have illustrations. +1